# Python 3 bytes.index: better way?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, byte

Just learned Python 3 in 7 days, and I have the feeling that there's a bit of a hole in my understanding of byte strings. In Python 3, suppose I have a byte string `b'1234'`. Its iterator returns integers:

```
Python 3.2.3 (default, May 26 2012, 18:49:27) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> for z in b'1234':
...   print(type(z))
... 
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'int'>
```

I can find an integer in the byte string (the definition of `in` is that it searches for equality):

```
>>> 0x32 in b'1234'
True
```

However, I would like to find the index of a given integer in the byte string. `bytes.index` requires a substring:

```
>>> b'1234'.index(b'2')
1
```

Now, if I have a variable `x` that I want to find, this is the best I've come up with:

```
>>> x = 0x32
>>> b'1234'.index(bytes([x]))
1
```

I know Python is more elegant than that. I'm clearly missing something obvious. Any ideas as to a simpler way to do this other than creating a sequence of a single integer? Or is that really it?

Comment: The question behind also is, why do you want to find the index of the byte?

Comment: If you must know :) It's part of a virtual machine, one of whose instructions needs the index of a byte found. It implements version 3 of the Z-machine spec, used to play Zork and other text adventures based on that engine. If you want to check it out, it's at http://code.google.com/p/pyzmachine. It's my first effort, so points for improvement are appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that's the way to do it.

It's not much different from the way to search for a character in a string based on its code point:

```
x = 0x32
i ='1234'.index(chr(x))
```

Comment: Interesting -- I had not realized that <code>chr()</code> created a string. It seems that, indeed, strings are the only way to represent one instance of a string's element type.

Comment: @RobertB: Yes. Python does not know the char type.  The character (unlike in other languages) is technically only the string with the length 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>>> bytearray(b'12345').index(0x32)
1
>>>> bytearray(b'12345').index(b'2')   
1
>>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, have a look at Mark Pilgrim's *Dive Into Python 3*, Chapter [4. Strings](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/strings.html), Section [4.6. Strings vs. Bytes](http://getpython3.com/diveintopython3/strings.html#byte-arrays).  It explains nicely what are the problems with older Python 2.x strings (that became the type *bytes* in Python 3) and how the new Python 3 *string* differs in principle.